# Has a better way to check word?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I suppose that `a` and `A` are same words. These are my methods as follow:

```
chars = 'aA'

def test_no_lower():
    for c in chars:
        if c in 'aA':
            pass

def test_lower():
    for c in chars:
        if c.lower() == 'a':
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    from timeit import timeit

    print timeit(test_no_lower)
    # -> 0.320052002777

    print timeit(test_lower)
    # -> 0.470894553251
```

I find that `test_no_lower` is faster than `test_lower`. I guess the reason `test_lower` calls `lower` function, so it do more one step to convert string than `test_no_lower`.

Has any better method can be faster than `test_no_lower`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general `if 'a' in c.lower()` is the best way to go about this. In Python3 you'd use `if 'a' in c.casefold()`.

If you're certain that you're only ever testing one character at a time, I don't see why you couldn't use the `if c in 'aA'`, but it seems like a narrow use case. Imagine if you needed to make sure that all the letters in a word were between `a` and `y` (your employer hates the letter "Z").

```
charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
all(c in charset for c in word)
```

compared to:

```
word.lower() == word
```

Comment: Your answer is awesome.